Using prismjs keep-markup plugin still displays <mark> tag in code
I am attempting to do some extra highlighting inside prismjs and I'm using the keep-markup example shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70030471/1721654
My code:
<pre class="line-numbers keep-markup">
    <code #codeele class="language-{{ language }}">
        {{code}}
    </code>
</pre>

I am getting the code snippet from the backend and updating the string by replacing the highlight word with ${highlightedWord}
 if(item.pseudocode && item.pseudocode.highlights.length > 0){
            item.pseudocode.highlights.forEach( (highlight: any) => {
                item.pseudocode.code = item.pseudocode.code.replace(highlight.keyword, `<mark>${highlight.keyword}</mark>`);
            })
        }

But in the end, it still looks like this:

According to the prismjs documentation it should just work.
https://prismjs.com/plugins/keep-markup/
I've also add "node_modules/prismjs/plugins/keep-markup/prism-keep-markup.min.js" to my angular.json scripts.
